# Out of Memory Error with Encoding.UTF8.GetString

Tags: .net, vb.net

This function

```
Public Function UnzipString(ByVal bByteBuffer() As Byte) As String

    Dim lastBytes(3) As Byte

    Array.Copy(bByteBuffer, bByteBuffer.Length - 4, lastBytes, 0, 4)
    Dim sBufferLength As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(lastBytes, 0)

    Dim sBuffer(sBufferLength - 1) As Byte
    Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream(bByteBuffer)
    Dim ds As New System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(ms, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress, True)
    ds.Read(sBuffer, 0, sBufferLength)
    Return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sBuffer)

End Function
```

Stops with an Out of Memory error on the Return statement, GetString call. sBuffer is pretty large, with 165 MB of (byte) data in it, but I'd still like it to work. Can anyone think of a way of getting this to work for large data sets ?

Comment: Do you really need the whole string in a single call? What are you planning on doing with it? It would normally be better to create a `StreamReader`. Note that your current code is broken, as you're ignoring the value returned by `Stream.Read`... it may well not read everything in a single call.

Comment: Is it reproducible on the first call to the method, or is this being called multiple times?  Is it running as a 32 or 64 bit process?  How much memory is in use by the process when it fails?

Comment: Its a 64 bit process, memory used by the host EXE (a service) is ~1GB on a 20GB machine. sBufferLength is 165,744,584. The string in this case subsequently gets written to a file, but this sub is also used to unzip other strings. The code has been in production for several years and never gone wrong, so I don't think its broke, but I take your point that it has the potential to break. I could live with a solution that takes sBuffer and writes it to a file directly, but would that actually have the same effect as the UTF8.GetString call ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing another sub that writes the byte array straight to a file, thus avoiding any in-memory presence of the whole unzipped content:

```
Public Sub UnzipStringToFile(bByteBuffer() As Byte, sFileName As String)

    '   This avoids the "out of memory" error when using UnzipString

    Using _
        ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream(bByteBuffer),
        ds As New System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(ms, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress, True),
        fs As System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.Create(sFileName)

        ds.CopyTo(fs)
        ds.Close()

    End Using

End Sub
```